# Why won't this Twitter follow button move down?

Tags: html, css, twitter

I have tried to add a button to follow a Twitter account on my website and I have tried all of the different types of vertical-align, setting them for the "twitter-follow-button" class but the button always stays at the top of my navbar.

Here's the webpage where it's not working: http://www.mineyc.com

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align only works for table cells. It's a common misconception that it can be used on other elements.

Use margins on the top and bottom.

`margin:12px 0px;`

on the `li` for the twitter button should do the job, you could do this by adding a css selector for it in your css or using inline styles.

Comment: This increases the height of the navbar too.

Answer (score 0):

You are floating the container to the right, so `vertical-align` won't achieve anything (vertical-align is not as simple as it sounds, you need to be working with something `inline-block`, or a table-cell).

As with your menu (floated left), try adding padding to get it in position. If you add this:

```
 padding: 12px 0;
```

to the `li` item containing your Twitter button, it lines up as you want.

Comment: This increases the height of the whole navbar too, is there a way to stop that?

Comment: reduce the padding until it doesn't. try 11px, then 10px etc.